# How to get recent files written to directory if 2 files are written program should detect 2 files using python

Tags: python

I am trying to get the recent files that are witten to my directory. Below is the code I am using.

```
 filelist = max(glob.iglob(path_to_midterm+"\\*.zip"), key=os.path.getctime)
```

This code is giving me the recent file. If there are multiple files written in the directory it still giving me 1 file. So, what I want is if  there are multiple files written at same time to get all of the files.  How do I get all files?

Comment: Doesn't the max() function only return the biggest of the set?

Comment: Keep the previous `ctime` and then search for all files whose `ctime` is greater than the previous `ctime`, e.g. `[f for f in glob.iglob(path_to_midterm+"\\*.zip") if os.path.getctime(f) > p_ctime]`

Comment: "At the same time" implies that this is actually possible.  It likely isn't.  These files will have timestamps that differ at the millisecond level probably.

Comment: @Scath Yeah. But if 2 files have same create time i was hoping it will return both. But i guess I was wrong. Thats the part i am stuck on

Comment: @JLH ohh yeah that i didnt thought. Sorry I am new to this. Learning my way in

Comment: Just take the max off and go through the files in the directory and get the ones with the correct time, but as @JLH said you won't be able to get many that are exactly the same might be able to get any from a certain day for example.

Comment: @AChampion thanks that solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd get all files, find out the oldest and use all which are within ten seconds of this time:

```
filenames_and_times = [ (filename, os.path.getctime(filename))
    for filename in glob.iglob(path_to_midterm+"\\*.zip") ]
time_of_last = max(filetime for (_, filetime) in filenames_and_times)
print [ filename
    for (filename, filetime) in filenames_and_times
    if filetime > time_of_last - 10.0 ]
```

Alternatively you could sort the list of filenames by the time and use the last four entries or so (depends on your usecase if this makes sense):

```
filenames_and_times.sort(key=lambda (f, t): t)
print filenames_and_times[-4:]
```